# Powershell match repeat only showing last occurrance

Tags: regex, powershell, match

Using Powershell to break up a string into patterns using -match I only see the last occurrence of a pattern:

```
$a = "1 0 8 string a 8 string b 10 final string"
$a -match '^(\d+) (\d+) ((\d+) (\D+)){0,}'
$matches
```

shows

```
True

Name   Value
----   -----
5      final string
4      10
3      10 final string
2      0
1      1
0      1 0 8 string a 8 string b 10 final string
```

How can I get this to populate "8","string a","8","string b", etc???

Thanks!

Comment: Your one group is used to match multiple segments of text, creating what are knowns as "captures". Group 3 contains all the captures, but is only showing you the last successful capture.

Comment: By the way, `{0,}` is exactly the same as `*`

Answer (score 1):

do you want this maybe?

```
([regex]::Matches($a,'^(\d+) (\d+) ((\d+) (\D+)){0,}') | select -expa groups )[3] |
 select -expa captures | select -expa value | -split '(\d+)' | ? { $_ } | % { $_.trim() }
```

or

```
((([regex]::Matches($a,'^(\d+) (\d+) ((\d+) (\D+)){0,}') | select -expa groups )[3] | select -expa captures | select -expa value) -split '(\d+)' | ? { $_ } | % { $_.trim() } | 
% { "`"$_`""} ) -join ','
```

Comment: Thanks - this is getting really close to what I need, I was looking to be able to process the extract an array

Comment: @JohnMcCabe If you add in youe question what you need maybe I can halp you more oh that

Comment: Something to the effect of referencing array element 0 and 1 then processing the #,character pair of elements 2 thru n.

Comment: `$a = "1 0 8 string a 8 string b 10 final string 6 stringc"`
`$b = [regex]::Matches($a,'^(\d+) (\d+) ((\d+) (\D+)){0,}')`  How do I reference $b.Value[1], $b.Value[2], etc?

Comment: OK - got it - I am appending the elements to an array and using that,  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use something like `$matches.Group[3].Capture[0]`, etc., to get all of the text matched by that single group.

I'm not very familiar with powershell syntax, but here's a reference to the library you need:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30wbz966.aspx#CaptureCollection